# not getting output from parmiko/ssh command

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am using paramiko/ssh/python to attempt to run a command on a remote server. When I ssh manually and run the command in question, I get the results I want. But if I use the python (co-opted from another thread on this site) below, there is no returned data. If I modify the command to be something more basic like 'pwd' or 'ls' I can then get the output. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

```
import paramiko  
import time  
import sys, os, select  
import select  
hostname='10.15.27.166'  
hostport=22  
cmd='tail -f /x/web/mlog.txt' #works  
#cmd='customexe -args1 -args2' #doesn't work  
client = paramiko.SSHClient()  
client.load_system_host_keys()  
client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)  
transport = client.get_transport()  
channel = transport.open_session()  
channel.exec_command(cmd)  
while True:  
  rl, wl, xl = select.select([channel],[],[],0.0)  
  if len(rl) > 0:  
    # Must be stdout  
    print channel.recv(1024)  
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Well, that depends highly on what the remote command looks like. Perhaps it needs to be run interactively (i.e., perhaps it checks for the user's terminal). Give us more information on that command.

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix, though not necessarily the root cause: When paramiko created the ssh connection, it did not run my bash_profile in my home directory on the remote server. So, I copied the commands from the bash_profile into the cmd variable and thus loaded various environment variables that I thought would have loaded automatically. Then the command "customexe ..." returned output as expected.